# Getting Invalid collection reference error when accessing Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am unable to from a new collection in Firestore using the below code. It always gives me the error:

> Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but Stores/Stored_Product_Storage has 2.

```
ProductClass dummyProduct = new ProductClass("dummyitem", 0, "none", 0);

db.collection("Stores").document("Stored_Product_Storage").collection(String.valueOf(docLocation)).add(dummyProduct);


db.collection("Stores").document("Stored_Product_Storage").collection(String.valueOf(docLocation))
        .whereGreaterThan("price", 0)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    products.clear();

                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                        String name = document.get("name").toString();
                        int price = Integer.parseInt(document.get("price").toString());
                        float units = Float.parseFloat(document.get("units").toString());
                        String unitType = document.get("unitType").toString();

                        ProductClass product = new ProductClass( name, price, unitType, units);

                        products.add(product);

                    }

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    storeProductUpdateActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

When I directly insert a string instead of String.valueOf(docLocation) then a new collection along with a document is created for inserting the dummy product data. But if I try to use a variable instead of directly giving the string in that field then it gives me the collection reference error. The same happens while reading the data. I am storing a custom string id in docLocation.Can anyone help me in fixing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly the case that `String.valueOf(docLocation)` is returning an empty string.  You'll need to check that before passing it to `document()`.

Comment: Yup,I actually fixed it with 10 minutes of posting here but then forgot to mark it as fixed here. And yes, docLocation didnt have any data.I set it to receive data that I earlier stored in shared preferences but turned out that it was empty which was due to another mistake.So I fixed it.Thanks for the reply though.And btw since I am new I don't know much about stackoverflow but why do I have downvotes?Is it because the answer was simple?